# Facebook like button?

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-page

For the last few days i've had an issue with the like button it's no longer working? I've been told it's due to fb:app_id is now required (so looks like i gotta edit over 17,000 pages to add this tag!) so i tried it on just one page however it still doesn't appear?

It has also now stopped the Tweet button appearing yet twitter is nothing to do with the iframe like button?

The page is this: [link](http://jordan.techmania-hosts.com/ilikethis/pages/breaking-up-with-your-girlfriend-by-moving-your-chair-on-jeremy-kyle) - please let me know if i'm missing something here..

It's kinda annoying if i have to use fb:app_id aswell now as i got over 17,000 pages that i'll need to edit to add the fb:app_id tag.

Also my other site doesn't have an app or a page so how would i use fb:app_id on that? I was using fb:admin before...

Comment: if to make a simple change you have to edit 17k+ pages then you really need to think about how your app works.

Comment: It's not an app though they are just pages for people to like it doesn't have an app but it worked before without an app and without fb:app_id tag, even the google ads don't show anymore. (I haven't changed anything, everythings just stopped working?)

Comment: what @piddl0r smartly meant is, you could make a dynamic database-driven web app to do the exact same thing using PHP or whatever other server-side language you like , and then you would only have to edit one file (the file that generates the pages). Editing 17000 pages seems ridiculous.

Comment: @Shai Mishali I do use a config file for most of the tags such as meta, og:image ect.. for the site just not the iframe and comment plugin. I thinking i might pay someone to code me an facebook app like the one i saw before by someone (was something like apps.facebook.com/something/45956856)

Answer (score 1):

On the page you link to, your FB:Like button code is commented out with `<!-- -->` so of course it won't appear.

Also, you have two `<div id="fb-root">` 's on your page and this will cause errors.  You need to make sure there is only one of those divs.

Comment: Hi, that was only while i was testing it i disabled that to try another iframe code but that didn't work either.. Since they updated the like button its stopped like, comments, google ads and tweet button all from appearing...

Comment: I've removed the other div however it's still not working. It was working fine but since all the facebook updates it's now this.

Google ads and Tweet button are even being effected (i think as they are not showing?)

Comment: won't let me edit the reply above? however it seems to be working on [this page](http://jordan.techmania-hosts.com/ilikethis/pages/im-not-addicted-to-texting-im-addicted-to-the-person-im-texting/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone above for your help i just remembered what a silly person i was and i remember i put this in my css file:

```
iframe {
      display: none;
}
```

so that's why it wasn't working, my bad! thanks everyone above anyway. (how can i close this as resolved?)